# Xpath: Inserting new delimiter after each iteration

Tags: xml, xpath

Current Xpath

```
//devices/device/@* | //devices/device/CMDB/HPSM_CI_ID
```

Result:

```
Linux,10.37.99.82,ELROND-LC3,ELROND,CI146826,
Windows,40.37.199.822,Mordor-LC3,Mordor,
                CI19765
            ,
Windows Events (NIC),10.30.70.45, BALROG-LC2, BALROG, Wcuties, fad.822,Mordor-LC3,
                CI19765
            ;
```

Notice that it returns all iterations of the query. When I add a concat and '|', it returns:

```
Linux,CI46826|
```

Essentially, I am just trying to get it to do this:

```
Linux, 10.37.99.82, ELROND-LC3, ELROND, CI146826 | Windows, 40.37.199.822, Mordor-LC3, Mordor,  CI19765 | Windows Events (NIC), 10.30.70.45, BALROG-LC2, BALROG, Wcuties, fad.822, Mordor-LC3, CI19765 |
```

Here is the XML:

```
<device-attributes>
<!--
    Attribute definitions
-->
<attribute-definitions>
    <category name="Location">
        <attribute name="Country"/>
        <attribute name="State"/>
        <attribute name="County"/>
        <attribute name="City"/>
        <attribute name="Campus"/>
        <attribute name="Building"/>
        <attribute name="Floor"/>
        <attribute name="Room"/>
    </category>
    <category name="Organization">
        <attribute name="Company"/>
        <attribute name="Division"/>
        <attribute name="BusinessUnit"/>
        <attribute name="Department"/>
        <attribute name="Group"/>
        <attribute name="Contact"/>
    </category>
    <category name="Owner">
        <attribute name="Manager"/>
        <attribute name="PrimaryAdministrator"/>
        <attribute name="BackupAdministrator"/>
    </category>
    <category name="Physical">
        <attribute name="Manufacturer"/>
        <attribute name="SerialNumber"/>
        <attribute name="AssetTagNumber"/>
        <attribute name="Voltage"/>
        <attribute name="UPSProtected"/>
        <attribute name="RackHeight"/>
        <attribute name="Depth"/>
        <attribute name="BTUOutput"/>
    </category>
    <category name="Function">
        <attribute name="PrimaryRole"/>
        <attribute name="SubRole1"/>
        <attribute name="SubRole2"/>
    </category>
    <category name="Importance">
        <attribute name="Value"/>
    </category>
    <category name="Vulnerability">
        <attribute name="Value"/>
    </category>
    <category name="Zone">
        <attribute name="WAN"/>
        <attribute name="LAN"/>
        <attribute name="Security"/>
        <attribute name="Operational"/>
    </category>
    <category name="Properties">
        <attribute name="CustomName"/>
        <attribute name="ResolvedName"/>
        <attribute name="Description"/>
    </category>
    <category name="SystemInformation">
        <attribute name="DomainName"/>
        <attribute name="SystemName"/>
        <attribute name="Identifier"/>
        <attribute name="Description"/>
    </category>
    <category name="CMDB">
        <attribute name="HPSM_CI_ID"/>
        <attribute name="HPSM_CI_COMMON_NAME"/>
        <attribute name="ASR_TIER_SCORE"/>
        <attribute name="NEZUMI_SCORE"/>
        <attribute name="ACAF_SCORE"/>
        <attribute name="ACAF_CRITICALITY"/>
    </category>
</attribute-definitions>

<devices>
<!--
    Devices
-->
    <device ipaddr="10.37.99.82" dtype="Linux" site="ELROND" node="ELROND-LC3">
        <Importance>
            <Value>
                1
            </Value>
        </Importance>
        <Vulnerability>
            <Value>
                1
            </Value>
        </Vulnerability>
        <Properties>
            <ResolvedName>
                kdcpmblrobo04.kdc.capitalone.com
            </ResolvedName>
        </Properties>
        <CMDB>
            <HPSM_CI_ID>
                CI146826
            </HPSM_CI_ID>
            <HPSM_CI_COMMON_NAME>
                kdcpmblrobo04
            </HPSM_CI_COMMON_NAME>
        </CMDB>
    </device>
    <device ipaddr="40.37.199.822" dtype="Windows" site="Mordor" node="Mordor-LC3">
        <Importance>
            <Value>
                1
            </Value>
        </Importance>
        <Vulnerability>
            <Value>
                1
            </Value>
        </Vulnerability>
        <Properties>
            <ResolvedName>
                kdcpmblrobo04.kdc.capitalone.com
            </ResolvedName>
        </Properties>
        <CMDB>
            <HPSM_CI_ID>
                CI19765
            </HPSM_CI_ID>
            <HPSM_CI_COMMON_NAME>
                FaceFace
            </HPSM_CI_COMMON_NAME>
        </CMDB>
    </device>
    <device ipaddr="10.30.70.45" dtype="Windows Events (NIC)" site="BALROG" node="BALROG-LC2">
        <Importance>
            <Value>
                1
            </Value>
        </Importance>
        <Vulnerability>
            <Value>
                1
            </Value>
        </Vulnerability>
        <Properties>
            <ResolvedName>
                sqlp05
            </ResolvedName>
        </Properties>
        <CMDB>
            <ASR_TIER_SCORE>

            </ASR_TIER_SCORE>
            <NEZUMI_SCORE>

            </NEZUMI_SCORE>
            <ACAF_SCORE>

            </ACAF_SCORE>
            <ACAF_CRITICALITY>
                Low
            </ACAF_CRITICALITY>
        </CMDB>
    </device>
    <device ipaddr="fad.822" dtype="Wcuties" node="Mordor-LC3">
        <Importance>
            <Value>
                1
            </Value>
        </Importance>
        <Vulnerability>
            <Value>
                1
            </Value>
        </Vulnerability>
        <Properties>
            <ResolvedName>
                kdcpmblrobo04.kdc.capitalone.com
            </ResolvedName>
        </Properties>
        <CMDB>
            <HPSM_CI_ID>
                CI19765
            </HPSM_CI_ID>
            <HPSM_CI_COMMON_NAME>
                FaceFace
            </HPSM_CI_COMMON_NAME>
        </CMDB>
    </device>
</devices>
</device-attributes>
```

I tried

```
concat(//device/device/@*, //devices/device/CMDB/HPSM_CI_ID, '|')
```

But to no avail as it truncates the answer after the first iteration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a for-each instruction.

```
concat(//device/device/@*, //devices/device/CMDB/HPSM_CI_ID, '|')
```

Will select all the nodes, not iterate over each. you need something like:

```
<xsl:for-each select="//device/device/@* | //devices/device/CMDB/HPSM_CI_ID">
  <xsl:value-of select="."/><xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: Is there anyway to do this via Xpath or is it going to have to be XSL? I ask because the platform I have to do this on can only seem to run Xpath 1.0

Comment: Sorry, I assumed you were using XSLT. It all depends on what program you are using to convert the xml.

Comment: The only information I can find on it is:

**"Takes a reference to an XML File which is then opened and the specified Xpath Query is run against the XML and returns the results in a form of a delimited list.**"

This is middle-man software which I typically use for PowerShell and other scripts, I know next to nothing about Xpath/XSL unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

In XPath 2.0 you can do

```
string-join((//device/device/@*, //devices/device/CMDB/HPSM_CI_ID), '|')
```

If you can't use XPath 2.0 then it's a good idea to make this clear in your question.